NextJS routes changing only through in app actions(buttons)
I have a Nextjs 13 app with nestjs in be and I want to know how to do, how to control routes.
I have in my app this scenario: User is in page/step1 he cant change route modifiying url name, if he do that he should remain on step1 (routes are in db) the only way he can go to the next page is to access in app button which looks  :
handlenextPage{   useSetCurrentPage("/battle/step2"); router.push("/battle/step2")} 
useSetCurrentPage:
export const useSetCurrentPage = async (currentPageToken: string) =\> {
const accessToken = document.cookie
.split('; ')
.find(row =\> row.startsWith('access-token'))
?.split('=')\[1\];

if (!accessToken) {
console.error('Access token not found');
return;
}



await updateCurrentPageInDb(accessToken, currentPageToken);

Question is how to do this router controll, what should I use?
I tried using middleware.ts and its working perfectly on local where response practically is instant but on online is not like that, there on button click nothing happens because after usesetcurrentpage instantly is running router.push and after routerpush is verifiying if token is same as in db but isnt because useSetCurrentPage need a time
middleware.ts:
import { getCurrentPageInDb } from "./services/currentPage/currentPage.service";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { parseCookie } from "utils";

export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
const cookieHeader = req.headers.get("cookie");

if (!cookieHeader) {
return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", req.url));
}

const cookies = parseCookie(cookieHeader);
const accessToken = cookies\["access-token"\];

if (!accessToken) {
return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", req.url));
}

const currentPage = await getCurrentPageInDb(accessToken);

if (currentPage && req.nextUrl.pathname !== currentPage) {
return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(currentPage, req.url));
}

return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
matcher: \["/battle/:path\*", "/admin/:path\*"\],
};
\`

what should I use and how should I use?

Okay So what I understood here is that when a user tries to navigate to some other page you want update your DB and this is taking time(expected behaviour) but because the url is changing in parallel the DB isn't getting updated.
Reason:
you are not waiting for the network call to complete.

As you mentioned, it takes time to make this request but the
router.push is not waiting for anyone hence the behaviour!



const useSetCurrentPage = async (currentPageToken: string) => {
            const accessToken = document.cookie
            .split('; ')
            .find(row => row.startsWith('access-token'))
            ?.split('=')[1];
            if (!accessToken) {
            console.error('Access token not found');
            return;
            }
            return (await updateCurrentPageInDb(accessToken, currentPageToken)).then(()=> router.push("/battle/step2"));
        }



and then
handlenextPage{   useSetCurrentPage("/battle/step2");} 

